# Cтатус человека на странице: онлайн или оффлайн

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать так, чтобы на странице был статус человека то есть "Онлайн" или "Оффлайн"

Comment: Спасибо за мысль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БД фиксировать последнюю активность всех пользователей. На странице где необходимо показать статус другого пользователя - проверять время последней активность, допустим если активность была меньше 10 минут назад то показывать что он онлайн. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Barton. Еще хочу добавить, что через js реализовать это не возможно, это обращайтесь за помощью к php и к СУБД например Mysql.